# How can I disable the javascript debugger in the Web Inspector for the iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, mobile-safari, mobile-website, web-inspector

I am using the Web Inspector in desktop Safari (Version 6.0.2 (7536.26.17)) (under the Develop menu) to debug Mobile Safari's interaction with a web application in the iOS Simulator (Version 6.0 (358.4)).

At the moment, I would like to simply monitor HTTP requests; I am not interested in stepping through the javascript code. However, the Web Inspector keeps dropping into the debugger, even though no break points are set. I have to repeatedly click the "continue" button to get the entire page to load.

How can I tell the Web Inspector not to debug javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting is there, I just overlooked it. In the Web Inspector in the pane on the left side, at the top, there are a bunch of icons. The second one from the right is a "breakpoint" icon. Click that. There are two entries at the top, "All Exceptions" and "All Uncaught Exceptions." I had "All Exceptions" enabled. Disabling that solved the problem.